# C++ error number allocation - are there any accepted standards?

Tags: c++, standards, error-code

Are there any conventions about which error numbers I should use in my C++ code?

Do I start at 1 or should I pick a high number and go from there?

An example was requested, so here it is:

```
#define ERR_EVERYTHING_IS_WRONG 42

try
{
    throw ERR_EVERYTHING_IS_WRONG;
}
catch(int err)
{
    //
}
```

Comment: What kind of error numbers are you talking about? I recommend clarifying the question with an example.

Comment: Don't use 42. That is never an error.

Comment: If I'm understanding your question right, there is one somewhat accepted standard in C++: don't. Use exceptions, that's what they're for. (But it's not really an answer to the question as asked, and you may actually be asking about returning something that isn't really an error.)

Comment: @CashCow That would be a good error for when everything has gone wrong... the universe and life included

Comment: Why the -1 from someone without a comment explaining why? This site is full of so very many helpful/patient people... but then there is always "that other guy". Ummm

Comment: "everything was wrong" is often the excuse used for your bridge contract being set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the best way is to follow standard for conventions of different errors in C++ codes is **Enum**

eg:

```
enum FILE_ERROR{
FILE_NOT_FOUND,          
FILE_NO_ACCESS,
FILE_BUSY
};
```

so in code u  can use FILE_NOT_FOUND as error number which is 0 . So this makes easy to understand what error type stands for what

Comment: no, FileNotFound is the other boolean that isn't True or False.

Comment: with enum classes in C++, one should static_cast to int to convert an enum type to int.

Comment: type of enum elements is an integer const  . So no need to converting or cast it again

Answer (score 2):

For try-catch, do not use numbers! Use a class derived from a standard exception class. Example:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class my_error : public std::runtime_error {
public:
  explicit my_error(const std::string& what_arg) : std::runtime_error(what_arg) {};
};
```

Usage ([Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ea47503584ced92f)):

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  try {
    throw my_error("You can even pass a string here!");
  } catch (const my_error& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what();
  }
}
```

Or simpler: use `std::runtime_error`

```
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  try {
    throw std::runtime_error("Error happened");
  } catch (const std::runtime_error& e) {
    std::cerr << e.what();
  }
}
```

---

Without standard library:

```
class my_error {
};

int main() {
  try {
    throw my_error();
  } catch (const my_error& e) {
    //TODO handle my_error
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not implementing the standard library. (I know you will assume that's an error on my part or a waste of time, but I assure you I am not for a couple of important reasons relating to my code). Thanks though.

Comment: *I am not implementing the standard library.* What do you mean by that? You are not using the standard library? You can create custom exception classes anyway without inheriting from `std::runtime_error`.

Comment: I am not using std. No includes at all! Crazy, I know :) I am told everytime I post :-/

Comment: @Beakie see my updated answer. Next time please share those "tiny" details when asking the question.

Comment: I was expecting an answer relating to numbers not exception classes. I didn't realise it was important. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @Beakie yep, pretty important if you want to throw them :) - for reserving numbers use `enum`s as in Siddesh Parmar's answer.

Comment: always catch by const&

Answer (score 1):

There is no rule, you can do whatever you want as long as you keep a logical way to assign it.

If you choose `3` for bad user input, keep it for only that error or you'll get lost really soon

Answer (score 1):

In C++ it is common to have 1 as success and 0 as error code, unlikely to C, where there are many functions returning 0 as success (strcmp, etc...)

this may be confusing sometimes, especially when interacting with C code, however I find that it helps a lot readability.

```
if(cplusplus_function()) {...}
```

is a lot more readable than

```
if(!c_function()){ ... }
```

remember also that you have exceptions to leverage in C++, and try to avoid nesting if-s

Answer (score 0):

You don't "throw" any number, you "throw" an exception, an object of a class that derives from `std::exception`.

Standard exceptions contain text, and do not actually contain an error number. You can however create different classes for different types of exceptions, and have different catch handlers dependent on which exception type was thrown.

Comment: Yes it works, but it is not the "accepted standard" to throw an int.